# Shapely Python NameError when using cascaded_union

Tags: python, shapely, import, nameerror

I am fairly new to Python and therefore my error-solving skills are not much yet developed.
I am using Python within a geoprocessing script which is supposed to use ogr (reading/writing shp) and shapely (geometry processing) to dissolve a shapefile with n polygons in it.

To accomplish that step I need the function "cascaded_union" in the shapely.ops module.
As soon as I have the import in my script
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
I am getting an Error even when I don't use the function anywhere in the script yet. That is why I suppose that this is not a usage rather than a installation/configuration error.

- running an Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
- Eclipse with PyDev
- installed shapely via Ubuntu repositories
- included path: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shapely

Error Message:

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/workspace/testproject/dissolve.py", line 3, in <module>
    from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shapely/ops.py", line 6, in <module>
    from shapely.geos import lgeos
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shapely/geos.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ctypes.util import find_library
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/util.py", line 89, in <module>
    import re, tempfile, errno
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 34, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py", line 90, in <module>
    ranf = random = sample = random_sample
NameError: name 'random_sample' is not defined
```

Content of dissolve.py:

```
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
```

The auto completion of the import works. So the packages are recognized, I guess.

Comment: Isn't the problem comin from the random module ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't shapely, it's numpy. Uninstall numpy and try again. Also, check to make sure that you're not using code like "from numpy import *" in your program. This will lead to conflicts between the stdlib random module needed by ctypes and numpy's random module.

Comment: but I need numpy within another part of my work. How can I solve this issue then? Any possibilities?

Comment: are you using "from numpy import *"? don't do that. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855845/pythons-random-module-made-inaccessible-by-numpys-random-module.

Comment: no I don't. I use numpy in another part of the script (different file) with "import numpy"